# How to fix this SQL Server Management Studio error?

Tags: ssms

I have problem with my SQL Server Management Studio, I use the 17.8.1 version. When opening the application, this error message appears:

[image]

How to fix this problem?

I've done the following to fix the issue but have not solved it yet.

- Ran Repair, no errors or warnings.
- Uninstalled completely then reinstalled

Comment: Can you please tell which operating system you are using?

Comment: @Asad i used Win 10 Enterprise (x64) (10.0, Build 17134)

Comment: It can be as a result of a any operating system error. Have you recently installed any update to the system, If not please check for the updates and install available updates.